# How to activate ModernUI application from native code?

Tags: c++, api, microsoft-metro, x86, windows-store-apps

I have native code executing (x86) in process of modernUI app, I need to activate the application. I can't find API for this.

Comment: What do you mean by modernUI ?! Any link to introduce it ?!

Comment: @MM.: That would be better known as Windows Metro.

Comment: Yes its Windows Metro application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it. **IApplicationActivationManager** should do the trick.